# Is it possible to number an enumerate list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have an enumerated list using `{enumerate}` that looks like the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Cat
\item Dog
\item Horse
\end{enumerate}
```

But I want to know if it's possible to number the entire list? So that if this is the third list in my document and I want to refer back to Dog, I can call it 3ii and so that my enumerated list would look something like:

3

i. Cat

ii. Dog

iii. Horse

Comment: Have a look at the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indents may need to be changed, but the structure is here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{listnumber}
\setcounter{listnumber}{0}
\newenvironment{enumeratelist}{%
  \addtocounter{listnumber}{1}%
  \noindent\arabic{listnumber}%
  \renewcommand\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}%
  \begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\parskip 1em\parindent 0in
\begin{document}

\begin{enumeratelist}
\item Cat
\item Dog
\item Horse
\end{enumeratelist}


\begin{enumeratelist}
\item Cat
\item Dog
\item Horse
\end{enumeratelist}


\begin{enumeratelist}
\item Cat
\item Dog
\item Horse
\end{enumeratelist}


\end{document}
```